# Insert bibliography on dissertate

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing

I downloaded a LaTex template for dissertation.
There is a file "references.bib", with a structure like:

```
@article{ArticleName,
  title={Title},
  author={Surname, Name},
  year={2000},
  publisher={Publisher}
}
```

The file to be compiled is this one:

```
\documentclass{Dissertate}

\begin{document}

% the front matter
\input{frontmatter/personalize}
\frontmatter
\setstretch{\dnormalspacing}

% include each chapter...
\setcounter{chapter}{0}  % start chapter numbering at 1
\include{chapters/introduction}
\include{chapters/chapter1}
\include{chapters/chapter2}
\include{chapters/chapter3}
\include{chapters/chapter4}
\include{chapters/chapter5}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
\bibliography{references}
\phantomsection
\cleardoublepage

\end{document}
```

I compile with XeLaTex and BibTex. After compiling with BibTex, I have this message:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian)
The top-level auxiliary file: dissertation.aux
The style file: IEEEtran.bst
A level-1 auxiliary file: chapters/introduction.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: chapters/chapter1.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: chapters/chapter2.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: chapters/chapter3.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: chapters/chapter4.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: chapters/chapter5.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file dissertation.aux
Database file #1: references.bib
-- IEEEtran.bst version 1.14 (2015/08/26) by Michael Shell.
-- http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/bibtex/
-- See the "IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO.pdf" manual for usage information.

Done.
```

The pdf generated have the section "reference", but without the references in the file "references.bib". Is an empty chapter.
Whats the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Is there a \cite command somewhere in your. tex file?

Comment: To extend @leandriis question, that might be the problem, try adding \nocite{*}

Comment: Now I add \nocite{*}, and it works. Problem solved, thank you